# php- foreach statement duplicating results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while and foreach loop that I want to use to print all of my results from a MySQL query.  Below is my code for the while statement and the foreach statements.

WHILE:

```
while ($row_questions = mysql_fetch_array($result_questions)) {

 $step_number[]      = $row_questions['step_number'];

 if ($row_questions['step_number_sub'] != 0) {
   $step_number_sub[]  = $row_questions['step_number_sub'];
 } else {
   $step_number_sub[]  = "0";
 };

 if ($row_questions['step_required'] != 0) {
   $step_required[]  = "*";
 } else {
   $step_required[]  = "";
 };

 $step_description[] = $row_questions['step_description'];
 $step_outcome[]     = $row_questions['step_outcome'];
 $step_equipment[]   = $row_questions['step_equipment'];
 $test_changes[]     = $row_questions['test_changes'];
};
```

and my FOREACH:

```
foreach ($step_number as $i => $step){
    $even_odd = ( '-odd' != $even_odd ) ? '-odd' : '';
    echo '<section class="zebra'.$even_odd.'">';
    echo '<div class="span-2 number"><strong>'.$step_number[$i].'</strong></div>';
    echo '<div class="span-20 description">'.$step_description[$i].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="span-2">'.$step_required[$i].'</div>';
    if ($step_outcome[$i] != null) {
      echo '<div class="span-22 outcome"><strong>Desired Outcome</strong><br>'.$step_outcome[$i].'</div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    echo '<article class="results">';
    echo '<div class="span-10">Did this step match the desired outcome?</div>';
    echo '<div class="span-10">Notes:</div>';
    echo '<div class="span-10">
          <select name="question_'.$step[$i].'" id="question_'.$step[$i].'" required aria-required="true">
          <option name="pass" value="Pass">Yes, this step was completed successfully</option>
          <option name="fail" value="Fail">No, this step failed to complete. See notes below</option>
          </select>
          </div>';
    echo '<div class="span-10"><textarea name="question_'.$step[$i].'" id="question_'.$step[$i].'" class="nots"></textarea></div>';
    echo '</article>';
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    echo '</section>';
};
```

I am getting multiple versions of the same results (4).  Thanks in advance for any help and let me know if you need any other info!

Comment: Whats the output of `print_r($step_number)` between these two loops?

Comment: Have you checked whether your query is creating the duplicates (by using phpmyadmin, for example?)

Comment: Masterful!  It was my SQL.  I am a dolt. Thanks so much Aerik!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use multiple arrays.  Use a class structure or array for each element. A simple way to do this:

```
while ($row_questions = mysql_fetch_array($result_questions))
    questions[] = $row_questions;

foreach( $questions as $question )
{
    $even_odd = ( '-odd' != $even_odd ) ? '-odd' : '';
    echo '<section class="zebra'.$even_odd.'">';
    echo '<div class="span-2 number"><strong>'.$question['step_number'].'</strong></div>';
    echo '<div class="span-20 description">'.$question['step_description'].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="span-2">'.$question['step_required'].'</div>';
    if ($question['step_outcome'] != null) 
    {
      echo '<div class="span-22 outcome"><strong>Desired Outcome</strong><br>'.$question['step_outcome'].'</div>';
    }
   ... you get the drift ...
  };
```

Comment: oh awesome! Even though the problem was in my SQL, this is a far better solution than what I had! Thanks so much -